# make column equal to another but different rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to make 1 column in excel equal to another but I have 2 issues:
- columns are in different sheets
- values in the first columns are placed in direct successive rows, but values in the other are placed in cells incremented by 4 rows each time

means if columns are in A & B, we should have 
A1=B2, A2=B6, A3=B10, ...

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In A1:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,(ROW(A1)*4-2)
```

Comment: Hi - I tried your answer on new excel sheet , it worked - but I tried it to match a columns starting B8, B9, B10,... in sheet "Crank D" to a column B4, B8, B12, ... in sheet "Bar B", I didn't succeed. Kindly which formula syntax to use

Comment: In B8, put `INDEX('Crank D'!$B:$B,(ROW(B8)-8)*4+8)`

Comment: I switched "Crank D" with "Bar B" It worked but it started giving me the sequence from B8 in sheet "Bar B". what to change so it starts giving me the sequence from B4 in sheet " Bar B "

Comment: Look, you also have to make some effort here! Try to understand how the formula works - then adjusting it to your needs is really easy! :-)

Comment: :D  ok just give me this answer. n I promise I will make the effort for the rest

Comment: +4 instead of +8 in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you use OFFSET then the rules might be easier to follow, e.g.

=OFFSET(**'Crank D'!B$4**,(ROWS(**B$8:B8**)-1)***4**,0)

The bold parts are those that are variable....

**'Crank D'!B$4** is the first value you want

**B8** is the first cell in which you enter the formula

**4** is the number of rows between each entry you want

Change those 3 as required